# Automatically creating a grid of images

Tags: graphics, python

I have several pdf images that I have generated with `matplotlib`. I want to be able to arrange them in an arbitrary grid. For this purpose I have written a python script that in turn writes and runs latex.

```python
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--images', nargs='+', help='List of images to be processed')
    parser.add_argument('--output', help='Output file name', default='output_grid.pdf')
    parser.add_argument('--grid', nargs=2, type=int, help='Grid dimensions (rows, columns)')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    assert len(args.images) == args.grid[0]*args.grid[1], "Number of images does not match grid dimensions"
    tex_outfile = "_{}_.tex".format(random.randint(0,100000))
    with open(tex_outfile, 'w') as f:
        f.write("\\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}\n")
        f.write("\\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx, color}\n")
        f.write("\\begin{document}\n")
        f.write("\\begin{{tabular}}{{{}}}\n".format(" c "*args.grid[1]))
        for k,v in enumerate(args.images):
            f.write("\\includegraphics[width={:.9f}\\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{{{}}}".format(1.0/(args.grid[1] + 1), v))
            if (k+1) % args.grid[1] != 0:
                f.write(" & ")
            else: 
                f.write(" \\\\\n")
        f.write("\\end{tabular}\n")
        f.write("\\end{document}\n")
    os.system("pdflatex {}".format(tex_outfile))
    os.system("mv {}.pdf {}".format(tex_outfile[:-4], args.output))
    os.system("rm {}*".format(tex_outfile[:-4]))
```

The above python code generates the below Latex, which is then run by `pdflatex` in the python code line `os.system("pdflatex {}".format(tex_outfile))`

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx, color}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ c  c }
\includegraphics[width=0.333333333\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{image1.pdf} & \includegraphics[width=0.333333333\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{image2.pdf} \\
\includegraphics[width=0.333333333\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{image3.pdf} & \includegraphics[width=0.333333333\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{image4.pdf} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The problem I have is that the images are not perfectly aligned, see this image (converted to png for stackexchange):

[image]

I think the alignment issue is due to y-ticks differing in length. Is there a way to fix this in the code I provided? Or an alternative that might be a better method (using `subplots` will not work as the individual images are already provided as pdfs).

Comment: If you are looking for a matplotlib solution, then maybe this question would be better suited for some other site? Maybe stackoverflow?

Comment: If you instead would like a latex solution, you should show your latex code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! I don't mean to spam you in the comments here, but yes – if you can show the LaTeX source output that your python generates, we can certainly help get *that* in a better state – and then you can incorporate the solution provided into your python script. As it stands, it's not trivial to follow the python script to 'build the LaTeX source in your head', as it were.

Comment: Apologies, I have added the LaTex code generated by the python code, for this example. Yes; I am looking for a LaTex solution (but of course open to others that may be better).

Comment: Please share the 4 images

Comment: On the LaTeX side specify height rather than width with keep aspectratio and let the images change in the horizontal direction only they will look better.

Comment: right align them not center so the left label length does not affect things and use `scale` not `width` so the images scale by the same amount so the plots will be the same size if they were the same size originally.

Comment: Thank you all, it seems @DavidCarlisle 's suggestion works well, all images are aligned. The `scale` value must be found with trial and error. Happy to post an answer if the code will be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right align them not center so the left label length does not affect things and use scale not width so the images scale by the same amount so the plots will be the same size if they were the same size originally.